# Unable to deploy python program with cx_freeze due to cv2

Tags: python, linux, cx-freeze, opencv

So I have a fairly large python program that I want to port to other machines (ubuntu 18.04) without having to install all the python packages and dependencies for each machine, I chose to use `cx_Freeze` for this and it seems to build the project fine into a single executable but the executable crashes when calling `cv2.imshow`. I managed to reproduce the error with this small snippet of code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('monke.jpg',0)
cv2.imshow("img", img)
```

this is my `cx_Freeze` build script:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": []}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for
# a console application).

setup(
    name = "test",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "My GUI application!",
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables = [Executable("cv2_test.py")]
)
```

and this is the error I get:

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/home/vaki/Desktop/cv2_test/build/exe.linux-x86_64-3.7/lib/cv2/qt/plugins" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: xcb.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

I also tried running the program with `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1` for a more detailed error output:

```
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/vaki/Desktop/cv2_test/build/exe.linux-x86_64-3.7/lib/cv2/qt/plugins" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/vaki/Desktop/cv2_test/build/exe.linux-x86_64-3.7" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/vaki/Desktop/cv2_test/build/exe.linux-x86_64-3.7/cv2_test"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/vaki/Desktop/cv2_test/build/exe.linux-x86_64-3.7/cv2_test'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/vaki/Desktop/cv2_test/build/exe.linux-x86_64-3.7/monke.jpg"
QElfParser: '/home/vaki/Desktop/cv2_test/build/exe.linux-x86_64-3.7/monke.jpg' is not an ELF object
"'/home/vaki/Desktop/cv2_test/build/exe.linux-x86_64-3.7/monke.jpg' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/vaki/Desktop/cv2_test/build/exe.linux-x86_64-3.7/lib/cv2/qt/plugins/platforms" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/vaki/Desktop/cv2_test/build/exe.linux-x86_64-3.7/lib/cv2/qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/vaki/Desktop/cv2_test/build/exe.linux-x86_64-3.7/lib/cv2/qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "xcb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QXcbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/vaki/Desktop/cv2_test/build/exe.linux-x86_64-3.7/platforms" ...
Cannot load library /home/vaki/Desktop/cv2_test/build/exe.linux-x86_64-3.7/lib/cv2/qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (libQt5XcbQpa-70670cdb.so.5.15.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
QLibraryPrivate::loadPlugin failed on "/home/vaki/Desktop/cv2_test/build/exe.linux-x86_64-3.7/lib/cv2/qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so" : "Cannot load library /home/vaki/Desktop/cv2_test/build/exe.linux-x86_64-3.7/lib/cv2/qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (libQt5XcbQpa-70670cdb.so.5.15.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)"
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/home/vaki/Desktop/cv2_test/build/exe.linux-x86_64-3.7/lib/cv2/qt/plugins" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: xcb.
```

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I tried using pyInstaller, but it doesn't manage to even build the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So thanks to jpeg from the other answer I managed to fix the issue by adding the following snippet of code to my builds script:

```
opencv_lib_src = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(cv2.__file__), '..', 'opencv_python.libs')
opencv_lib_dst = os.path.join('lib', 'opencv_python.libs')
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], 
                     "excludes": [],
                     "include_files": [(opencv_lib_src , opencv_lib_dst)]}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that the `cv2/qt/plugins` does not get completely included by cx_Freeze.

Try to modify the beginning of your build script as follows:

```py
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os
import cv2

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
plugins_source_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(cv2.__file__), 'qt', 'plugins')
plugins_target_path = os.path.join('lib', 'cv2', 'qt', 'plugins')
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"],
                     "excludes": [],
                     "include_files": [(plugins_source_path, plugins_target_path)]}
...
```

(not tested, you might need to fine-tune)

This should tell cx_Freeze to include to whole folder `cv2/qt/plugins` at the right place, see the cx_Freeze [documentation](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html#build-exe).

Comment: good suggestion, I tried it but it doesn't seem to work. even though the long error message says it cannot open `libqxcb.so` i double checked and the file does indeed exist at the location it tried. but then later on in the error message it says `Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/home/vaki/Desktop/cv2_test/build/exe.linux-x86_64-3.7/lib/cv2/qt/plugins"` even though it was found. indicating that it is finding it it but for whatever reason can't use it

Comment: Ok, sorry. Maybe then `libqxcb.so` depends on another shared library which is not included by cx_Freeze (or an incompatible version of this dependency may also be included from another package). Do you see any `.so` file inside `cv2` which is missing in the frozen location? Did you try my proposal with the whole folders `cv2` or `cv2/qt` instead of `cv2/qt/plugins`? Have you tried to look at the dependencies of `libqxcb.so` with some dependency analysis tool?

Comment: I tried running diff on the two different `cv2` folders and they are mostly the same except some .py files become .pyc which I think makes sense. I have no experience with dependency analysis tools, can you recommend any to me that you think would work with .so files?

Comment: I've no experience with dependency analysis under linux but as far as I understand, this is what the command `ldd` is for.

Comment: Another track: maybe your executable misses some Qt library. Is Qt installed in your system? Do you have any PyQt or PySide package in your Python installation? If yes, maybe you need to import this Qt package in your script `cv2_test.py` to let it be properly included by cx_Freeze as well.

Comment: Yet another track: have you tried the brand new version 6.6. of cx_Freeze? There have been some improvements made there, also with respect to the inclusion of shared libraries.

Comment: yeah I'm using 6.6  of cx_Freeze, no im not using any PyQT or PySide in my code, ldd gave me some interesting results that I'm looking into now, so there are dependencies missing and in the proper cv2 installation it finds them in `cv2/qt/plugins/platforms/../../../../opencv_python.libs/` which is why I didn't see them in in the cv2 folder  I'm gonna try messing around with opencv_python.libs that and see what happens

Comment: ok, so I got it working by adding this to my build script 
`plugins_source_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(cv2.__file__), '..', 'opencv_python.libs')`

`plugins_target_path = os.path.join('lib', 'opencv_python.libs')`
`build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"],  "excludes": [], "include_files": [(plugins_source_path, plugins_target_path)]}`